# How much money am I allowed to transfer to India into my own Indian account as a non-Indian foreigner?

Tags: taxes, bank-account, india

I am a non-Indian foreigner and recently opened a savings bank account in India. Is there a maximum amount I am allowed to transfer taxfree under Indian Law to India for my living expenses here? I read in some other postings that for an NRE account there is no limitations and also if you are a Indian Citizen not residing in India. Is this also applicable to non-Indian foreigners who are having an own bank account in India?

Comment: The answer might depend on your nationality, whether there is a tax treaty between the country of your citizenship and India, and whether you are a permanent resident of India or in India on some kind of long-term (but not permanent) visa.  (Also, if your parents or grandparents were citizens of India or were born in "undivided" India (i.e. in what are now the countries of India, Pakistan, and Bangladesh), a whole different set of rules are applicable).

Answer (score 1):

From you question I understand that you are not an Indian citizen, are staying in India, and transferring your funds for your living / expenses in India.
There is no limit on such transfers and the amount is not taxed.

The tax comes into picture if you are treated as a resident in India from a tax perspective. Even then the tax is not because you have transferred the funds into India, but the policy of taxing global income.

The article at http://www.pwc.in/en_IN/in/assets/pdfs/foreign-nationals-working-in-india.pdf should give you more inputs.